# Flink on yarn: how to add external jars class path in local Client

Tags: apache-flink

I tried to deploy my application to flink on yarn with cli, Unfortunately,it's fail with below Exception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lredis/clients/jedis/JedisCluster;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:72)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.clean(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1548)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream.clean(DataStream.java:183)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream.flatMap(DataStream.java:551)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.DataStream.flatMap(DataStream.scala:594)
    at com.hypers.hwt.realtime.top.HwtRealTimeTopRunner.executeLateStream(HwtRealTimeTop.scala:138)
    at com.hypers.hwt.realtime.top.HwtRealTimeTopRunner.run(HwtRealTimeTop.scala:72)
    at com.hypers.hwt.realtime.top.HwtRealTimeTop$.main(HwtRealTimeTop.scala:265)
    at com.hypers.hwt.realtime.top.HwtRealTimeTop.main(HwtRealTimeTop.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:528)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:419)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:381)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:838)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:259)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:1086)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend$2.call(CliFrontend.java:1133)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend$2.call(CliFrontend.java:1130)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext$1.run(HadoopSecurityContext.java:43)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1709)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:40)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1130)
```

I already use -yt parameter to distribute my external jars,but still fail.
Actually,flink submit job with 3 step:

1. wrap code and build graph in client
2. client submit job to jobmanager
3. jobmanager distribute job to taskmanager

### problem

In long time test,I found this Exception is happen in step1. And step1 is run in local by YarnClusterClient. And I know this problem will be solved by add my external jars in $FLINK_HOME/lib,but it will cause conflict with other application

### Expect

So I want to know if there are any way to add external jars class path in local?

**Addtion**

```
class LateFlatMap(conf: FlinkJedisClusterConfig) extends RichFlatMapFunction[(PvAccBean, UvAccBean), Iterable[(String, Array[Byte])]] {
  var jedisCluster: JedisCluster = null

  override def open(properties: Configuration): Unit = {
   val genericObjectPoolConfig = new GenericObjectPoolConfig()
       genericObjectPoolConfig.setMaxIdle(conf.getMaxIdle())
       genericObjectPoolConfig.setMaxTotal(conf.getMaxTotal())
       genericObjectPoolConfig.setMinIdle(conf.getMinIdle())
   jedisCluster = new JedisCluster(conf.getNodes(), conf.getConnectionTimeout(),
   conf.getMaxRedirections(), genericObjectPoolConfig)
 }

 @Override
  override def close(): Unit = {
   jedisCluster.close()
 }
 ...
}
```

Comment: Please paste the exception to stack overflow itself, rather than link to external image.

Comment: It seems that this class is needed in some of your `flatMap` function. It is serialized there, therefore it is needed in taskmangers rather than client. Could you post some code where do you use `RedisCluster`?

Comment: thanks, actually I use it In class LateFlatMap which extends RichFlatMapFunction

Comment: As I addition, I use it like   stream.flatMap(new LateFlatMap).

Comment: However, I think it can't submit to jobManager successfully,because this Exception throw by CliFrontend.executeProgram method according to stack, and this method called before getJobGraph,so I guess it build graph fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I see two possibilities:

1. Add your 3rd party libs to your jobs jar by building a fat jar. Each major build system can do so (e.g. [Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) or [SBT Assembly Plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly)). This would be my preferred solution
2. If you want to use your 3rd party libs for all of your flink jobs you can add them to flinks jars directory before your start your cluster. This will also work but offer you less flexibility.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks answer, I considered fat jar,however it too large(about 800m). Also I'm sure my thired part libs was updated to hdfs with -yt parameter in flink cli, and my job is crashed when submit job rather than runtime

Comment: If you transfer the files using `yarnship` you still have to add them to the classpath using `-C`.

Comment: I added -C parameter, Unfortunately,it fail with same Exception.

Comment: How did you specified your classpath at the -C parameter. This one has to be full qualified (e.g. `hdfs://apps/flink/lib/jedis.jar`)

Comment: flink -yt parameter will update libs to hdfs://user/hdfs/.flink/${appicationId}/, However ${appicationId} is dynamic,and I can't know it before starting

Comment: I see - does it work for you if you upload your 3rd party libs once manualy to HDFS and try whether this works together with `-C`. Just as a prove of concept

Comment: @jay Wong Actually you've to upload jars one by one using ```-C```, just like ```--jars``` in spark submit

Comment: In Flink 1.12 both options `-yt` and `-C` have been removed. Solutions like 1) fat-jar and 2) user jars in FLINK_HOME/lib have serious drawbacks. I have created an issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-23972

Answer (score 0):

Tried all options combined -C and -yt, external jars added in classpaths and added in yarn.ship.directories but failing when initializing mq connection factory. Same working when placed in flink lib.
Wondering still this is not working at end of 2020

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
bin/start-scala-shell.sh local -a <full_external_jar_path>
```